# Restore VSTO Controls after Word Crash

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto

While I was adding controls to a VSTO MS Word template in Visual Studio, the copy of Word that was serving as the form editor crashed taking Visual Studio down with it.  When I restarted Visual Studio, I discovered that while the controls I'd spent the last several hours inserting and naming were preserved in the ThisDocument.Designer.vb file the associated .dotx file apparently was not autosaved because none of the new controls were on it.

Is there any way to restore the controls to the .dotx file from the designer; or am I stuck with having to redo all of the lost work?

I'm using VSTO for Office 2007 if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have built your application at least once then you can copy the .dotx file created in your bin folder.

Comment: Unfortunately I hadn't built anything yet before the crash.  It was a large form and I was still in the initial process of plopping various controls onto it.

Comment: Try Method 3: Search for AutoRecover files http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316951

Comment: That was a bust at the time of the crash.  The document Word recovered didn't have any of my unsaved work.